# Set up proxy for selenide?

Tags: java, maven, proxy

Is there any possibility to set up proxy for selenide library?

I start autotests from command line with maven comman:

```
mvn clean test [some params] site
```

It was possible to change maven setting to use proxy (in `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`) so it can download dependencies.

But one of dependencies is [selenine](/questions/tagged/selenine) which requests `http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/` to check/download last version of chromedriver.exe. And here I've got an error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com

io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:475)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:458)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:472)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:458)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:219)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverBinaryManager.setupBinaryPath(WebDriverBinaryManager.java:16)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:55)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.createDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:231)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:118)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverRunner.java:136)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Navigator.navigateToAbsoluteUrl(Navigator.java:68)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Navigator.open(Navigator.java:32)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:95)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:69)
```

**UPDATE:**

If the network is not available, but there is already any previously downloaded version of chromedriver, this version would be used:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
[main] WARN io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Network not available. F
orcing the use of cache
[main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Found chromedriver in ca
che: C:\Users\XUser\.m2\repository\webdriver\chromedriver\win32\2.38\chr
omedriver.exe
[main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.chro
me.driver as C:\Users\XUser\.m2\repository\webdriver\chromedriver\win32\
2.38\chromedriver.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a system property to set proxy for web driver manager:

```
System.setProperty("wdm.proxy", url);    // url as "http://host:port"
System.setProperty("wdm.proxyUser", url);
System.setProperty("wdm.proxyPass", url);
```

More info https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager#configuration

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not possible now.
Could you register a github issue at https://github.com/codeborne/selenide?

By the way, you can just disable automatic downloading of webdriver in Selenide:

Configuration.driverManagerEnabled = false;

Comment: Done https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/issues/748

Answer (score 1):

You will notice that on the proxy request failure, you'll see a failure on a request to `http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com` and you'll notice the reason your firewall blocks it is because their is a redirect on that query that tries to download from an AWS location.  A URL that might look something like `https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/25354393/....`.

So, your best bet is to ask your company to allow downloads from the  backup URL, which is `http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors`, as defined [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/main/resources/webdrivermanager.properties).

IF you aren't able to request allowing that location, then I would suggest including the drivers  (usually stored in .m2/repository/webdriver) in your project root folder and set the System env variable to define where Selenide will look for the local driver.

Good luck.   I spent days trying to work around this.  It is not likely, in my opinion, that setting proxy env variable will work for you UNLESS you have an un-authenticated proxy.   Setting `wdm.proxyPass` might work if your proxy is not Basic auth.

NOTE:  Keep in mind that Java, by default, is configured to ignore Basic auth on proxy URLs unless you override the system env property.